# How to convert IEC 611131-3 (PLC) source code to ontology

Tags: ontology, plc

I have read alot of scientific papers and search the internet but I still could not find the appropriate answer to my question. I know what ontology is but the main question is even if create the ontology (on protege) where the source code will reside in the ontology as it is just a relationship model.

and second question is do I have to write the code in turtle/RDF-XML format or it can be done automatically?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand what you are hoping to accomplish, could you clarify?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question is about “Semantic Web” and has nothing to do with PLC programming.

I can recommend the following book:
Semantic Web for the Working Ontologist
by Dean Allemang, James Hendler
Publisher: Morgan Kaufmann
Published: Juli 2011